# In My VB.NET forms application I want to update the labeltext on the form continuously without using the Me.Refresh() Method how do I do this?

Tags: vb.net

This is the Function which Returns a random Integer continuously and Raises an event(each time) which calls a handler in the codebehind of the windows forms called Eventing

```
  Public Function MyNumber() As Int64

        While (True)
            Dim myInt As Int64

            Randomize()
            myInt = CInt(Int((100 * Rnd()) + 1))

            RaiseEvent ValueChanged(myInt)
            Return myInt

        End While

    End Function
```

In the CodeBehind of the Forms  I use this code to update the label to the value returned from the function to update the label text

```
   Public Sub Eventing(e As Int64) Handles CoolObject.ValueChanged

        ActiveForm.Refresh()


        Label1.Text = e.ToString

    End Sub
```

The Problem is : The code works well and the Label1 updated continuously but the entire form freezes
None of the other buttons on the form respond and I have to forcefully stop it on visual studio

Comment: In the MyNumber method, you're kicking off an infinite loop.  That's blocking the UI.  Perhaps you want to look at doing something with threading or timers.  Would also suggest using the random class rather than the old Rnd() function

Comment: Use a `Timer` and change the `Text` of the `Label` in the `Tick` event handler. You'll probably get a maximum of about 20 changes per second but why exactly would you even want that many? A `Label` is to display text to the user and it would be a blur with 20 changes per second so what us is it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies, I used the BackgroundWorker thread to overcome this problem

Comment: ``BackgroundWorker`` is not recommended. You can consider using multithreading.